# How do I prevent a user from sharing their token?

Tags: authentication, security, authorization, backend, load-balancing

Let's say I have implemented an authentication system to access a given resource. The user enters their username and password, maybe even a 2fa code and then they are given an access token that they send along with each request for that resource. Then when the user tries to access that resource the backend checks if that token is present, then valid and if it is both of these things it returns a response with no error.

How do I make sure that the user does not send their token out for anyone to use? If they do, then anyone will be able to access all of the content that this user can access as long as the token they have remains valid, without the need for them to know that user's password. I saw 1 company check if the IP address of the request if the same as the IP address used to generate a token, but that doesn't scale very well and if the user is using a mobile device and change networks their IP address will change and the token will be no longer valid.

Also with that approach a user might create a token while connected to a VPN and then tell the people that the user will share their token with, to connect to that same VPN when they're using that user's token. I saw many replies to that question, but none of them seem to given an actual answer.

The token I refer to here might be a JWT, or anything else - that's not really relevant in this case.

To be clear, I'm not strictly tring to prevent a third party to steal a user's token and then use it (that too of course), but rather I'm trying to prevent a user from willingly sharing their token with others.

Comment: It would be helpful to understand why you are trying to do this. You mention this is not about stopping an attacker stealing the token, but about willing sharing of the token. Why is that a problem? Understanding the driver behind the desired behaviour can help people answer the question.

Comment: Well... say some content is paywalled. Then one user can pay for it and then share their token with others so that they can access it for free (let's assume the user won't download the content and share the content itself)